# JSON passed to controller has no value

Tags: json, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am unable to get my JSON to my controller, and I can't figure out why the value I get in javascript isn't being passed to the controller. Here is my ajax post in my javascript:

```
this.save = function () {
        var data = ko.toJSON(this.Routines);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "CreateJson",
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (!result.success)
                    alert("test")
                else { }
            }
        })
    }
```

now data contains

```
[{"routine_name":"new routine","duration":"20","rest":"10","rounds":1}]
```

which is what I want, but the controller shows nothing. Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateJson(t_routine routine, string data)
    {

        var message = "success";
        return Json(message);
    }
```

As I understand it, MVC 3+ automatically receives JSON without any need for parameters like my string data, I just threw it in there to try and figure out if I'm getting anything at all. data is null and routine shows 0's and null for values. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you verified it is hitting the proper URL? What does firebug show you in network when the request is triggered? Perhaps try a prefix of / for the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `t_routine` represents the server side type for

```
[{"routine_name":"new routine","duration":"20","rest":"10","rounds":1}]
```

Then it might be enough to call `JSON.stringify` on the `ko.toJSON` result like this

```
this.save = function () {
    var data = JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON(this.Routines));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "CreateJson",
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (!result.success)
                alert("test")
            else { }
        }
    })
}
```

the data parameter on your controller action is not needed then and you most likely need to change the `t_routine` parameter to `t_routine[]`

Comment: It seems all I needed was the [] on my model parameter. The JSON.stringify  causes the parameter to be null but with the default ko.toJSON I get what I need in the controller. Problem solved after banging my head on the wall for a while, and prompt too. much appreciated...